# I messed up with libstdc++6

Tags: libstdc++

I messed up with /usr/lib/libstdc++6 while trying to install teamspeak. So there I am, I have no more libstdc++6 file and I'm trying everything I can. I cannot use apt-get or aptitude anymore (I'm on debian). What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the `deb` package for your system directly from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libstdc%2B%2B6 (you may need to use a different computer, or a simple tool like `curl` or `wget`).

If `dpkg` is still working, use `dpkg -i <.deb file>` to install it.

Otherwise, the `deb` may be extracted using `ar x <.deb file>`, and the data files can be extracted with `tar xvzf data.tar.gz`. You can then `mv` the files from `./usr/lib` into the right place.